# Node unexpected identifier 'of ' in for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, npm

I am running an fork of a node based chat server using web sockets,
And after some server issues I pulled the project from github, and was greeted with a node error: ( even though the code was working before )

```
var server = new ws.Server({host: config.host, port: config.port})
console.log("Started server on " + config.host + ":" + config.port)

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('close', function() {
        try {
            if (socket.channel) {
                for (var client of server.clients) {
                    if (client.nick == socket.nick) {
                        client.connectionCounter--;
                    }
                }
```

Node quits giving an un expected identifier error pointing to the 'of ' in the for loop. Help would be appreciated.

Toasty

Comment: What version of node.js are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is a part of new ES2015 standard and not supported well yet, therefore you need to run node with **--harmony** flag